# MYSQL: Find element given a JSON_ARRAY of strings

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have tried to figure out a way to find elements given a JSON_ARRAY of strings. What I want to achieve is a `contains all` functionality.

Say I have a table called `Movies` with the columns `name` and `genre` and a table called `Genre` with the column `id`.

Movies

```
NAME      GENRE
Batman    1 
Batman    2  
Aquaman   2  
Joker     3  
IT        4
```

Genre

```
ID   NAME
1    Drama 
2    Action  
3    Thriller  
4    Horror
```

So now if I have a JSON_ARRAY with

```
SET @array = JSON_ARRAY("Action", "Drama");
```

How do a create a stored procedure that given this JSON_ARRAY returns `Batman`?

I think the solution is SQL recursion, but I'm not sure...

```
SET @array = JSON_ARRAY("Action", "Drama");  
sproc.GetMovieGivenGenres(@array, @out_movie);
SELECT @out_movie; --> Batman
```

Comment: Note! The genre for the movies are totally made up! They might not be correct ;)

Comment: Where does the JSON array come from?

Answer (score 1):

We can try making use of the `JSON_SEARCH()` function, which has the ability to search JSON arrays:

```
SELECT
    m.NAME
FROM Movies m
INNER JOIN Genre g
    ON m.GENRE = g.ID
GROUP BY
    m.NAME
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN JSON_SEARCH(@array, 'one', g.NAME) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) =
    JSON_LENGTH(@array);
```

The `JSON_SEARCH` function will return a non `NULL` value should a given genre be found in the input array, for each movie.  A matching movie is one which contains all genres in the input array.

Answer (score 1):

In mySQL 8 you can use [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) to convert the JSON arry into a table. Then you can join the generated table with your two tables:

```
SET @array = JSON_ARRAY("Action", "Drama");  

select m.NAME
from json_table(
  @array,
  '$[*]' columns (genre_name varchar(50) path '$')
) j
join Genre g on g.NAME = j.genre_name
join Movies m on m.GENRE = g.ID
group by m.NAME
having count(*) = json_length(@array);
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5m838JcN64g7jwstb3Umsz/0)

This way MySQL will be able to use an index on `Genre(NAME)`.